# Easy JSON encoding with Python

Tags: python, json, serialization

I'm quite new to python (I use python 3), and i'm trying to serialize a class with one string and two lists as members in JSon. I found that there's a json lib in the python standart but it seems that I need to manually implement a serialization method. Is there a JSon encoder where I can simply pass an object, and receive the serialized object as string without having to implement a serialization method.
Example:

```
class MyClass:
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_name = "me"
    my_list = {"one","two"}
    my_obj = MyClass()
    my_obj.name = my_name;
    my_obj.my_list = my_list


    serialized_object = JSONserializer.serialize(my_obj).
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does the Python version is important? I mean, are you able to do it in 2.x, but unable to do it in 3.0?

Comment: Yes it does, most of the libraries seems to have changed from 2.x to 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know of anything pre-built, but you can write one if your objects are simple enough. Override the default method in the JSONEncoder to look at inspect.getmembers(obj) (inspect is a more readable way of getting at sets of attributes in `__dict__`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import inspect
from json import JSONEncoder


class TreeNode:

    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


class ObjectJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, reject):
        is_not_method = lambda o: not inspect.isroutine(o)
        non_methods = inspect.getmembers(reject, is_not_method)
        return {attr: value for attr, value in non_methods
                if not attr.startswith('__')}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = TreeNode(42,
        TreeNode(24),
        TreeNode(242),
    )
    print(ObjectJSONEncoder().encode(tree))
```

**Update:** @Alexandre Deschamps says isroutine works better than is method for some input.

Comment: Thank you for the anwser, it almost does the trick except for two things. The  is_not_method = lambda o: not inspect.ismethod(o) seems to also need the not inspect.isroutine(o) statement. It looks like in python a built-in method is a limit case. Also, my class needs a list to be serialized with. it looks like the elements in the list do not get serialized with it.

Comment: @Alexandre Deschamps: I don't knwo what you mean... if you change those numbers in `__main__` to lists of numbers, it serializes just fine.

Comment: Ok, I just found out I was the problem. I was using the {} instead of [] to make a list. As I said, I'm new to the language. It works fine. Just add the "not inspect.isroutine" to your example in case other people needs it. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @Alexandre Deschamps: Ah! That's not a list, that's a `set` datatype. It has no order, so there's not a straightforward mapping to JSON datatypes. If you stick an `if isinstance(reject, set): return list(reject)` in there, it'll work -- it'll just assign an arbitrary order to the values in the set in the resulting JSON array.

Comment: It seems we saw it at the same time :P

Answer (score 3):

How would you expect the `json` library to know how to serialize arbitrary classes?

In your case, if your class is simple enough, you might be able to get away something like

```
foo = FooObject() # or whatever
json_string = json.dumps(foo.__dict__)
```

to just serialize the object's members.

Deserialization would then need to be something like

```
foo_data = json.loads(json_string)
foo = FooObject(**foo_data)
```

Comment: Nah, it doesnt seems to work because my class has two members, which is a string and a list of strings

Comment: It works for me: http://gist.github.com/574291.  If your object really only has two members, a string and a list of strings, then the serialization will work.  The deserialization technique I'm using relies on your object's `__init__` function to take arguments with the same names as the members.  See the gist above for a working example.

Comment: @WillMcCutchen Thanks for the inspiration to use `dict`. I wanted to do a similar thing, and although my object (from a SOAP request) didn't have a `__dict__` method, calling `dict(soapObj)` gave me a nicely printed JSON string. I'm also new to python, and this isn't an obvious technique, so I'm glad you mentioned it!

Answer (score 0):

How about the [JSONEncoder](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) class?

**update**

I must have skipped over the part about the data being contained in a class.  If you want sane serialization of arbitrary Python objects without the need to extend the encoder, then maybe you can use a combination of [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pickle.html) and `json`.  When pickling, use protocol = 0 to serialize the data as human-readable ASCII.

Comment: Still, i need to encode a class, and not only a simple type or an array. This class seems to require a manually defined serialization method in order to serialize a class. Maybe I'm wrong since I'm new with the language, but when I tested that's what I got.

Comment: `pickle`'s idea of human-readable is: `(i__main__
Map
p0
(dp1
S'towers'
p2
(lp3
(i__main__
Tower
p4
(dp5
S'attack'
p6
I10
sbasS'creeps'
p7
(lp8
S'one string creep in a list'
p9
asb.` Compared to JSON, that is hardly human-readable.

Comment: Substitute "printable" for "human-readable".  My point was that the protocol 0 pickle could be serialized safely as a JSON string if he insisted on using JSON for shuffling python objects about.