# What is for Python as json_encode for PHP

Tags: php, python, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy JSON encoding with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679306/easy-json-encoding-with-python)

I want to get a record from database and built it in to json. I know we can do it with json_encode when using PHP. But how can we do it in Python

Comment: if theres something, there is a Library for anything in Python, 'import antigravity' ftw!

Comment: "Didn't spend fifteen seconds on Google" needs to be a close reason.

Comment: If you cant answer, left this question. Why getting irritated?. This site is specifically for Programmers and Google is generally for all the things. Here i can get experts with updates. And I can get multiple views. So if u dont like to answer, leave stackoverflow. Dont make beginner programmers like me out.

Comment: 'irritated'?  No.  We're educating you on how to ask a **good** question. Your question was downvoted for reasons.  We're providing the reasons.  You can complain that you don't want to learn.  In which case, perhaps you should leave StackOverflow.  We're not leaving beginners out.  We're educating beginners.  Step 1.  Use Google.  Step 2.  Read the Python Library.  Step 3.  Post code that doesn't work.  If you can't do that, you're not really a "programmer".

Comment: So I had to research first on Google. I dont have to visit stackoverflow first?. Great!

Comment: @Rajasekar: why type a long question into SO when you can get the Python docs on json as the first response from google("python json")

Comment: @Rajasekar: I expect that the majority of irritated people, aside from perhaps being a little cranky, feel this way because your question as it stands is answered by typing "python json" into Google search and hitting "I'm feeling lucky". You're not asking a question it takes a programmer to answer and you're displaying a frightening lack of inititative. Your question does not solicit multiple view points from experts. If you are unable to resolve relatively simple problems yourself like this, then perhaps programming and technology in general isn't your ideal vocation.

Comment: Thanks friends!. Anymore Downvotes?

Comment: @Rajasekar: You can, if you want, either edit the question or close it.  You are free to **fix** or **improve** your question.

Answer (score 9):

```
# Python 2.6+
import json
result = json.dumps(value)
or
# Python 2.6+
import json
json.dump(value, out_file)
```

Got if from google first result. http://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.json-encode/

Please do your research before asking simple, searchable questions!

Comment: then the question may be, what json implementation is most stable/featured/available on Python3. Not asking, but isn't that style of hints is welcome?

Answer (score 2):

There are several json implementations for Python. I like simplejson because it's, well, simple.